# How do I get the equation of the line given this slope and graph?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This might be really low level for you guys but I just don't understand.!

The graph is $y=1/(x-1)$ and the given slope is $-1$.

I have to get the equation of the tangent line given the slope and graph.

So, I tried making it equal $y=-x+k$

I got $$x^2-x-kx-k+1=0$$
I tried performing the quadratic on it and got it down to: 
$$k^2+6k-3=0$$
I'm just really confused now and the book doesn't explain what to do...

Thanks for any input...

Comment: Is this calculus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

The method you have followed is legitimate but without using calculus.

$$\text{Here we have, }\frac1{x-1}=-x+k$$

$$\text{On rearrangement, }  x^2-(k+1)x+k+1=0$$

As you already know, the discriminant needs to zero for tangency.

$\implies (k+1)^2-4\cdot1\cdot(k+1)=0\iff (k+1)(k+1-4)=0$

$\cdots$

---

Now using calculus, we know the slope $$=\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac1{(x-1)^2}$$

Now we have $$-\frac1{(x-1)^2}=-1$$

Find $x$ and the corresponding $y$ from the given equation.

Then you know how to find the equation of a line  given a point and slope.

Comment: @LoadingCode, my pleasure. I've also completed your method which needed minor rectification.